# Signing APK breaks installation

Tags: android, apk, signing

I am resigning an APK with my own keys using the command line  `jarsigner.exe -keystore Keys.jks base.apk debug0`, after deleting META-INF/CERT.RSA, CERT.SF and MANIFEST.MF, without touching anything else.

My issue is that after resiging, installing via `adb install base.apk` gives me the error `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-2]`.

How can I solve this? In the AndroidManifest extractNativeLibs is set to false, at least as far as apktool can decode it. So I do not see any reason the libs should be extraced at all...

Comment: The error message is usually an indication that the apk contains native libraries that do not match the architecture of the device you are installing the application.

Comment: thank you, but as i already stated i can install the apk before resigning it, and cannot after resigning it. During the signing process there are no changes made to the file structure.

Comment: on which device are you installing the application? Using jarsigner will probably not support more recent signing schemes, so this information might be corrupt and result in such an error. Try using apksigner instead, which ensures that the correct signing scheme is cleared / used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get it to work i had to

1. zipalign the apk (`zipalign.exe -p 4 base.apk base_aligned.apk`)
2. sign it using apksigner (`apksigner.exe sign --ks Store.ks base_aligned.apk`)